# Read output of shell command in meteor

Tags: javascript, shell, meteor, stdout

I'm trying to ping a remote server to check if it's online or not. The flow is like this:

1) User insert target Hostname

2) Meteor execute command 'nmap -p 22 hostname'

3) Meteor read and parse the output, to check the status of the target.

I've been able to execute a command aynchronously, for example mkdir, that allow me to verify later that it worked.

Unfortunately it seems I'm not able to wait for the reply. My code, inside /server/poller.coffee is:

```
Meteor.methods

 check_if_open: (target_server) ->

     result = ''

     exec = Npm.require('child_process').exec

     result = exec 'nmap -p ' + target_server.port + ' ' + target_server.host

     return result
```

This should execute exec synchronously, shouldn't it? Any other approach using Futures, ShellJS, AsyncWrap, failed with meteor refusing to start as soon as the node package was installed. It seems I can install only via meteor add (mrt).

My client side code, located at /client/views/home/home.coffee , is:

```
Template.home.events 

    'submit form': (e) ->

        e.preventDefault()
        console.log "Calling the connect button"

        server_target =
           host: $(e.target).find("[name=hostname]").val()
           port: $(e.target).find("[name=port]").val()
           password: $(e.target).find("[name=password]").val()


        result = ''

        result = Meteor.call('check_if_open', server_target)

        console.log "You pressed the connect button" 

        console.log ' ' + result
```

Result is always null. Result should be a child process object, and has a stdout attribute, but such attribute is null.

What am I doing wrong? How do I read the output? I'm forced to do it asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use some kind of async wrapping, `child_process.exec` is strictly asynchronous. Here's how you could use Futures:

```
# In top-level code:
# I didn't need to install anything with npm,
# this just worked.
Future = Npm.require("fibers/future")

# in the method:
fut = new Future()
# Warning: if you do this, you're probably vulnerable to "shell injection"
# e.g. the user might set target_server.host to something like "blah.com; rm -rf /"
exec "nmap -p #{target_server.port} #{target_server.host}", (err, stdout, stderr) ->
  fut.return [err, stdout, stderr]
[err, stdout, stderr] = fut.wait()
if err?
  throw new Meteor.Error(...)
# do stuff with stdout and stderr
# note that these are Buffer objects, you might need to manually
# convert them to strings if you want to send them to the client
```

When you call the method on the client, you have to use an async callback. There's no fibers on the client.

```
console.log "You pressed the connect button"
Meteor.call "check_if_open", server_target, (err, result) ->
  if err?
    # handle the error
  else
    console.log result
```

Comment: I think I'm onto something. I'm trying to convert buffer to string, then I can validate your answer.

Comment: it works but it's poorly formatted. I'm using toString(), do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: this might be worth opening a different question. Thank you so much for your help !!!